# sharepoint search OR query with filter

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, filter, search-query

I had the following query:

```
https://[tenant].sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?querytext='Path:"https://one365dev1.sharepoint.com/teams/privegroep/Gedeelde%20%20documenten/*%22Isdocument=1"'&Properties=%27EnableDynamicGroups:true'&selectproperties='Title,ServerRedirectedURL,LastModifiedTime,FileType%27&sortlist=%27LastModifiedTime:descending'&rowlimit=10'
```

but then I realized that it needs to support both /sites/ and /teams/ and thus decided to use an OR query to search in both places for the content. It works now but I am clueless of how to implement the  (*%22Isdocument=1) part of the query.

the current query:

```
https://one365dev1.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?querytext='Path:"https://[tenant].sharepoint.com/teams/privegroep/Gedeelde%20%20documenten/"+OR++Path:"https://[tenant].sharepoint.com/sites/privegroep/Gedeelde%20%20documenten/"'&Properties='EnableDynamicGroups:true'&selectproperties='Title,ServerRedirectedURL,LastModifiedTime,FileType%27&sortlist=%27LastModifiedTime:descending'
```

Does anyone have any idea of how to go about adding the filter?

Answer (score 0):

Add parentheses. Also, I would not advise using IsDocument=True because it excludes certain file types. I typically use ContentTypeId:0x0101. I would also advise adding trimduplicates=false since it useually trims way too much if set to true, which is the default

https://one365dev1.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?querytext='**(** Path:"https://[tenant].sharepoint.com/teams/privegroep/Gedeelde%20%20documenten/"%20OR%020Path:"https://[tenant].sharepoint.com/sites/privegroep/Gedeelde%20%20documenten/"**)%20AND%20ContentTypeId:0x0101**'&Properties='EnableDynamicGroups:true'&selectproperties='Title,ServerRedirectedURL,LastModifiedTime,FileType%27&sortlist=%27LastModifiedTime:descending'**&trimduplicates=false**